# Opening Sentinel 2 images with GDAL in Python

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2

I'm trying to open Sentinel-2 images with python, and as far as I can tell, I have GDAL 2.1 installed, which (so I understand) ships with a Sentinel 2 driver. At least, the lines

```
from osgeo import gdal
for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount()):
    drv = gdal.GetDriver(i)
    if drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DCAP_RASTER):
        print(drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DMD_LONGNAME), drv.GetMetadataItem(gdal.DMD_EXTENSIONS))
```

include "Sentinel 2" on the list of outputs.

However,

```
gdal.Open(filename, GA_ReadOnly)
```

returns "None" for filenames that point at the zip-files from scihub, the xml-file or the jp2-files. Similarly, the gdalinfo tool returns that it is not able to recognise the file format.

Any pointers on where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: My GDAL 2.1.1 can open jp2 files.

Comment: Which product format iteration of Sentinel-2 are you using? Scenes after 2016-12-06 have a new format (PDS 14) which is not implemented yet in GDAL trunk.

Comment: Right - it works with files that are older than that.